# Can Controller fully replace what http handler does?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to know if controller can fully replace http handler when no view involved. The function looks similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Content("No view involved here", "text/plain");
}
```

or:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return File("test.pdf", "application/pdf");
}
```

or:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Json(new { foo = "bar" });
}
```

In all those examples, there's no view involved. The controller acts as an HTTP handler.